# How can I write to a compactlogix plc using cpppo?

Tags: python-2.7, raspberry-pi3

I am very new to programming so please bear with me.  I am trying to make a small HMI program using a raspberry pi 3 to communicate with a L35E compactlogix.  I have made on using visual studio express written in C#.  This is my first time using raspberry.  I have read online that python works very well.  I'm still learning my way around python and Linux, but have found code online that I can read the tags from the plc using this code:

```
from __future__ import print_function

from cpppo.history import timestamp

from cpppo.server.enip import client

host = "10.10.10.48"

tags = [ "Bit1", "Bit2", "Timer.PRE" ]

with client.connector( host=host ) as conn:

    for index,descr,op,reply,status,value in conn.pipeline(
            operations=client.parse_operations( tags ), depth=2 ):
        print( "%s: %20s: %s" % ( timestamp(), descr, value ))
```

I'll admit I just copied this in holes that I could find my way through what all of it means.  I know what most of this is, but I cannot find much about cpppo online and I cannot figure how to write to a tag.  Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

To start up a minimal "simulated" CompactLogix PLC hosting some Tags:

```
$ python -m cpppo.server.enip -v real=REAL reals=REAL[100] dint=DINT dints=DINT[100]
```

Now, to read/write some tags, I would recommend using the cpppo.server.enip.get_attribute 'proxy' API, as it is probably the simplest and quickest way to read/write *Logix PLCs:

```
$ python
>>> from cpppo.server.enip.get_attribute import proxy
>>> with proxy( "localhost" ) as via:
...  list(via.write(["dint=10","dint","reals[0-3]","reals[1]=1.234","reals[0-3]","reals[1]=4.567"],"reals[0-3]"))
...
         dint=10 == True
            dint == 10
      reals[0-3] == 0.0, 4.56699991226, 0.0, 0.0
  reals[1]=1.234 == True
      reals[0-3] == 0.0, 1.23399996758, 0.0, 0.0
  reals[1]=4.567 == True
[True, [10], [0.0, 4.566999912261963, 0.0, 0.0], True, [0.0, 1.2339999675750732, 0.0, 0.0], True]
>>>
```

Note that this will not work with MicroLogix PLCs (or simple, non-routing CIP devices such as an Allen-Bradley PowerFlex); for these, use the proxy_simple class.  See cpppo/server/enip/ab.py for an example.

Comment: What's up sir.... I really like your `cpppo` Python module and how it can poll data from PLC machine network sensors and such. I wanted to share a potential enhancement of code I found on one of your GitHub posts I wanted to send to you on this post, see the answer by `John Zwinck` as using this method rather than the `x, = proxy_simple(host).read("<TagName>")` sped the polling rate up tremendously and I was testing with a gram weigher sensors that can get three weights in one second. I will verify and accept once they are running but we need to talk more man.

Comment: Perhaps you already know this though but regardless just in case I wanted to share with you at a minimum. I will be testing more of your `cpppo` modules as time permits but I like it sir so thank you for your contributions with it.